# Error Handling in Scatter-Gather (Mule 4)

Tags: mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-component, mule4, mule-esb

I have a question.

In an interview, I was asked if one of the routes of scatter-gather fail, will we get the output. I replied with a no as scatter-gather always gives a consolidated payload taken from all routes, and then they asked me if I still want to get the payload from the successful routes, what should I do -> I answered with Try scope and on-error continue.  (I hope I was right here, please explain if I wasn't).

The next scenario they gave me was like this: If I have an on-error-propagate set for the scatter-gather and I also have a payload in that. So when the route fails and the handler comes to on-error-propagate, will the payload present there be printed or not. My answer to this question was a yes and I said that because on-error-propagate executes all its steps, the payload present inside its scope will be printed and then the flow will exit.

I don't know if that was right or not, so please help me with the correct answer for this scenario.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right platform for these question but I'll try to answer them.

> I was asked if one of the routes of scatter-gather fail, will we get the output. I replied with a no as scatter-gather always gives a consolidated payload taken from all routes

Scatter-gather executes all routes simultaneously and generates a LinkedHashMap of all the Mule Events (not just payloads). The payload from each event can certainly be extracted or functions like flatten() can be used to flatten the contents linearly. If one of the routes fail and no error handling is done, an error object will be introduced and scatter-gather will fail.

> they asked me if I still want to get the payload from the successful routes, what should I do -> I answered with Try scope and on-error continue.

Your answer seems good to me. Although, please note that on-error-continue should be on another flow that scatter-gather is calling. Having it in the same flow as scatter-gather may suppress the error raised but will not continue executing the next component in same flow.

> If I have an on-error-propagate set for the scatter-gather and I also have a payload in that. So when the route fails and the handler comes to on-error-propagate, will the payload present there be printed or not.

The statement is a bit confusing to me as it doesn't specify the placement of the on-error-propagate. If a printing component is inside the on-error-propagate scope and the handler comes to on-error-propagate, it will certainly print. However, if all it has is the payload, the flow will never go to the next component and an error object will be returned to the parent flow (or error is thrown if there's no parent flow).